# Zip 4 or more async calls using livedata

Tags: java, android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

Is there any possible way of using livedata to run multiple async calls in parallel??

Let say I have 4 async calls. I want to wait until everything is done and later use the result from all the 4 calls accordingly.

One way I can think of is this

```
public class MakeParallel {
    private final CountDownLatch countDown = new CountDownLatch(4);

    public void firstCall() {
        Transformation.map(makeFirstCall(), input -> {
            if(input.isSuccessful()) {
                countDownLatch.countDown();
                checkResult();
            }
            return input;
        } 
    }

    public void secondCall() {
        Transformation.map(makeSecondCall(), input -> {
            if(input.isSuccessful()) {
                countDownLatch.countDown();
                checkResult();
            }
            return input;
        } 
    }

    void checkResult() {
        if(countDownLatch.getCount == 0) {
            // Result is ready
        } else {
            // Something has error
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any better way to resolve this scenario??

Comment: I think that is the area where RxJava would excel at making your life easier!

Comment: I know but for some reason I can't use rxjava.

Comment: Then you are on your own. LiveData wasn't designed to solve that problem. You may solve that will ol' good AsyncTask where you can pass object of the class with those methods and call there one after another

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So the trick is to use MediatorLiveData and have it observe each LiveData object and zip the changes into a collection of some sort.

```
public static LiveData<ArrayList<Object>> zipLiveData(LiveData<Object>... liveItems){
    final ArrayList<Object> zippedObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    final MediatorLiveData<ArrayList<Object>> mediator = new MediatorLiveData<>();
    for(LiveData<Object> item: liveItems){
        mediator.addSource(item, new Observer<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable Object o) {
                if(!zippedObjects.contains(o)){
                    zippedObjects.add(o);
                }
                mediator.setValue(zippedObjects);
            }
        });
    }
    return mediator;
}
```

Or in Kotlin:

```
fun zipLiveData(vararg liveItems: LiveData<*>): LiveData<ArrayList<Any>> {
return MediatorLiveData<ArrayList<Any>>().apply {
    val zippedObjects = ArrayList<Any>()
    liveItems.forEach {
        addSource(it, { item ->
            if (! zippedObjects.contains(item as Any)) {
                zippedObjects.add(item)
            }
            value = zippedObjects
        })
    }
}}
```

This solution has no type safety. Feel free to customize to your needs!

Answer (score 2):

This will allow you to have 3 liveData zipped in one. It's easy to know what to do if you need more than 3.

```
fun <A,B,C> zippedLiveData(a: LiveData<A>, b: LiveData<B>, c: LiveData<C>): LiveData<Pair<A, Pair<B,C>>> {
        return MediatorLiveData<Pair<A, Pair<B,C>>>().apply {
            var lastA: A? = null
            var lastB: B? = null
            var lastC: C? = null

            fun update() {
                val localLastA = lastA
                val localLastB = lastB
                val localLastC = lastC
                if (localLastA != null && localLastB != null && localLastC != null)
                    this.value = Pair(localLastA, Pair(localLastB, localLastC))
            }

            addSource(a) {
                lastA = it
                update()
            }
            addSource(b) {
                lastB = it
                update()
            }
            addSource(c) {
                lastC = it
                update()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should have used Triple<A,B,C> instead of nested Pairs.